Selenium test suite with 180+ cases experiencing high CPU usage due to lingering ChromeDriver.exe processes
My Selenium test suite with 180+ Chrome browser tests experiences high CPU usage (100%) and suite failures. While I close the browser after each test, Chrome.exe remains as a background process, causing system freezes.
Chrome Version : Version 124.0.6367.156 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Chrome Driver Version : https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/**124.0.6367.155/**win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
enter image description here
enter image description here
Execution was once browser is close after test execution it should kill the chrome.exe process as well the same is not happening with firefox browser and test are running without any issue

I'm not sure what you want us to do with this info. You provided no code to show how you create or destroy driver instances, etc. We're running 2k tests / day and having no issues. Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code as text, properly indented and formatted. Also, add a tag for the language you are using.

Also, in one sentence you mention the chromedriver.exe process but in two others you mention chrome.exe... which one is it? Edit your question and clarify it.
